# UIButton setImage not working after creating button in IB

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have an IBOutlet UIButton that I added to a scroll view in IB.  I set its type to custom, then in viewDidLoad I have:

```
[self.featuredButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"featuredNormal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.featuredButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"featuredSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

The image doesn't appear...why not?

Comment: Is it connected to a featuredButton outlet in IB?

Comment: yes... I don't get it...

Comment: The files only added to one of my targets, had to add them to the others.  Duh... whoops...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[self.featuredButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"featuredNormal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.featuredButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"featuredSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```